Distance Between Space and Time-Dependent Functions in the $2$-Norm
Suppose I want to measure the "distance" between two functions $u$ and $u_h: [0,T] \times (\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2) \to \mathbb{R}$. How would I go about this? I know that, for example, if we had $v, v_h: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, the distance between $v$ and $v_h$ as measured in the 2-norm would be
$$
\|v - v_h\|_{2} = \sqrt{\int_{\Omega} (v - v_h)^2 dx}.
$$
However, the time dependence obscures things a bit. My intuition is that in the case of the former, the proper expression would be
$$
\|u - u_h\|_{2} = \sqrt{\int_{0}^T\int_{\Omega} (u(t,\mathbf{x}) - u_h(t, \mathbf{x}))^2 d\mathbf{x}dt}.
$$
Am I correct or is there something I'm missing here?

What you wrote is the definition of the norm of $L^2(0,T; L^2(\Omega))$ or of $L^2( (0,T)\times \Omega)$. If it is an appropriate choice for your problem is impossible to answer.
